# Why am I not getting any results from this SQL query (MS Access)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two tables, one is a local table in Access 2010 (**Employees**) and the other is a linked table in a SQL Server 2014 database (**dbo_Employees**). The query is run inside Access.

For reference, both tables are identical. Same columns, same data. They are literally copies of one another. The only difference is that I deleted one record from the SQL Server table. I did this because the query I'm trying to run is to find all the records in the **Employees** table that match records that exist in the **dbo_Employees** table. This should return all but the one deleted record. While it does exist in the Employees table, since it doesn't exist in the dbo_Employees table, it would be excluded in the results. Here is the query:

```
select Employees.ID
from Employees
where Employees.ID IN (SELECT dbo_Employees.ID FROM dbo_Employees)
```

When I run this, I get nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show some sample data of these tables?  I don't think they are as identical as you believe they are.

Comment: Yes. If I open either table I can see the data and if I run a SELECT query on the ID field on either table I can see the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have matching data in both tables?

What does

```
SELECT
    Employees.ID
    , dbo_Employees.ID
FROM Employees 
    INNER JOIN dbo_Employees ON Employees.ID = dbo_Employees.ID
```

return? Does it return any rows?

Otherwise, what does the following query return?

```
SELECT 
    Employees.ID
    , dbo_Employees.ID
FROM Employees 
    FULL JOIN dbo_Employees ON Employees.ID = dbo_Employees.ID
```

You can use this second query to see what data matches in both of your tables. The query will output the data in both tables while putting the matching ID values on the same row and displaying a `NULL` value in one or the other table's corresponding ID column if there is no match.

*(I know this is not a legitimate answer, it's more of a comment, but it's the first things OP should check)*

Comment: To first answer your questions: The first query returns 0 rows. The second query returned a syntax error (in the FROM statement). I don't think Access likes FULL JOIN. At any rate, this helped me figure out what was going wrong and it was something I'd done wrong. The ID field in the Access table was set to AutoNumber, which made it differ from the source it was copied from. In trying to figure out why your queries returned nothing, I took visual look at the data trying to identify anything and I found it. Thanks for the help. Now that I know what's going on I can deal with it.